# Одна статья - рядом выдача на другие статьи

Tags: php, mysql

С БД MySQL с помощью пхп на сайте есть статьи,  ссылки такого типа `index.php?id=1`,
то есть показывает первую запись в таблице, где `id=1`. Вывод статьи осуществляется примерно таким кодом

```
<?=stripslashes($row6['bodytext']);?>
```

Но теперь такая проблема - есть вторая таблица, в которой тоже статьи, 
во второй таблице есть 3-4 статьи, которые являются дополнением к статье с первой таблцы 
. Скажем, в первои таблице есть статья с `id=45`, во второй таблице есть статьи `id=1`, `id=2`.

Как сделать так, что б когда человек просматривает статью с первой табилцы `id=45`, на странице сбоку, ниже или еще, где были ссылки на статьи со второй таблицы `id=1` и `id=2`.

Comment: Должна быть связь между таблицами, а выборку надо делать JOIN-ом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно без джойна

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1,table2 t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id
```

*t2.id* это должен быть и id статьи из таблицы *table1* - с его помощью и будут связываться статьи из разных таблиц.

Answer (score 1):

если правельно понял:
таблица 1:
id | name | text
таблица 2:
id | name | text | ownerID

если примерно так, то

```
select
table1.name as name // Имя стати
table1.text as text // Текст статьи
table2.name as owner // Имя сопутствующей статьи
table2.ownerID // Ид сопутствующей статьи
from 
table1
left join
table2 // присоиденяете Вторую таблицу с дочерними
on table1.id = table2.ownerID // Задаете соответсвие по Ид заглавной статьи
where table1.id = id // где id - Ид вашей статьи
```

Comment: а как это расписать в пхп коде готовом? просто не очень силен в кодах. просто добавить 
<?
?> и все ?

Comment: @meravaz нет, <? ?> не хватит. Соединение с базой, запрос в базу, обработка результата.